# Cannot Use Flex and Bison Together on Qt

Tags: c++, qt, bison, flex-lexer

I am developing a project which I have to develop a compiler(actually a parser) besides the main project. I am using Qt 5.3 and Windows (But the result is almost the same on Ubuntu 14.04).
I am experienced in using flex and bison, however this time, firs I develop a Scanner and then Parser. I test the scanner carefully and made sure it is error less. but as I add the parser to the project many errors occurred.(for example undefined reference to `yylex()`, however I declared `extern int yylex()` and I cannot use library as I will mention) and after that when I eliminate the parser, some features which worked before are not working now! for example, now I cannot use `#include <QDebug>`!
When I use this header file, Compiler say there are many errors(77 error) in this library! I got confused, it has been two days I am working on this and there is no progress.
I used "Custom Build Steps" and I set the path to `${sourceDir}`. In addition I added `lex.yy.c`,`y.tab.c` in `SOURCES` and `y.tab.h` in `HEADERS` in `.pro` file.
I learned how to use flex and bison via [here](http://aquamentus.com/tut_lexyacc.html) for the first time. and for those errors I read the followings:
[Undefined Reference to `yylex()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28211952/y-tab-c-undefined-reference-to-yylex)
[How to Integrate Flex and Bison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412446/how-to-integrate-flex-and-bison-with-qt-project)
and some other links...

Comment: May be `extern "C" int yylex();` will help?

Comment: @user4419802: Didn't work!

Comment: What is _the first_ error?

Comment: @user4419802: undefined reference to yylex()

Answer (score 1):

Qt programs are in C++, not C.

If you have not-too-ancient versions of flex and bison, you will have no problem compiling their generated code using C++, but you need to tell the compiler that they are to be compiled in C++. (Using a combination of C and C++ is certainly possible but it requires some care.)

Using gcc, it should be sufficient to make sure that the names of the files generated by bison and flex have a `.cc` extension instead of `.c`, which you can do using the `-o` command-line option. (That's highly recommended in any case because it lets you choose more meaningful filenames then `y.tab.c` and `lex.yy.c`.) That requires some adjustments to your Makefile. (You can also use the `%output "filename"` directive in `bison` and `%option outfile="filename"` in `flex`, but you'll still need to adjust the dependencies in your Makefile.)

Another, less recommended, option is to use the `-x c++` command-line option to gcc.

Without more details about the toolset you are using on Windows, it is not easy to give more advice, particularly for me (since I have 0 experience in Windows toolsets). But the key is to ensure that both files are compiled as C++.

From the fact that you are trying to `#include` a Qt header, it seems like compiling the scanner and parser as C programs is not practical. But if I am misunderstanding your project and neither the scanner nor the parser require C++, then you can do so; you'll need to declare `extern "C" int yylex();` in the C++ translation unit which calls `yylex`. (Don't put this declaration in the scanner.l file; it won't work if you're compiling with C.)

Answer (score 0):

C++ setup of flex/bison is tricky. Check out this example project:

https://github.com/ezaquarii/bison-flex-cpp-example

It is a complete, working C++ Flex and Bison "interpreter", encapsulated in a class. In fact I used it few times with Qt 4.8.